# 405 : Client Error: Not Allowed for huggingface url

Tags: huggingface-transformers, http-status-code-405, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to follow the huggingface tutorial on finetuning models for summarization.
All I'm trying is to load the t5 tokenizer.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("t5-small")
```

And I get the following error:
[image]
...
...
[image]
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the issue for me. You can add

```
import os
os.environ['TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE'] = 'yes'
```

Quoting sgugger from [here](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/requests-exceptions-httperror-404-client-error-not-found-for-url-https-huggingface-co-api-bert-models-bert/9728).

> No that’s not a bug, the method tries to detect if a more recent version of the model is available, which is why it connects to the repo. To work fully offline, you need to set the environment variable TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE to 1 or yes (see [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode) 313).

Comment: Thank you. I did try that but it still gives me the same error. I cannot access anything on huggingface now, not just transformers. I just tried to get the Stanford CoreNLP model from huggingface and it throw an error :(